# Calling library function after exploiting buffer overflow crashes the program

Tags: c, assembly, stack, buffer-overflow, memory-alignment

I'm trying to perform a simple buffer overflow using the following program

```
void not_called() {
  printf("Enjoy your shell\n");
  char* name[2];
  name[0] = "/bin/sh";
  name[1] = NULL;
  execve(name[0], name, NULL);
}

void vulnerable_function(char* string) {
  char buffer[12];
  strcpy(buffer, string);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("Starting!\n");
  vulnerable_function(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

However when feeding it with

```
./hello `python -c 'print "A"*20 + "\x80\x1e"'`
```

with hello being compiled with

```
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wl,-no_pie hello.c -o hello
```

on OS X 10.11.6, the program crashes. I confirmed that this happens already after changing the program flow - it lands at `0x1e80` and prints "Enjoy...", however the `execve` seems to be failing.

Trace shows that an error occurred at **`0x1ed4`**, which is *past* the `0x1ecf execve` call, but  it didn't proceed to `/bin/sh` between crashing. 
The `%eax, -0x20(%ebp)` found under that address is obviously meant to fail, since saved `ebp` was overwritten when return address was, but **what is bugging me, is that it should never reach that line**.

Here's some output from lldb:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x42b83, 0x97f772f0 libdyld.dylib`misaligned_stack_error_, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x97f772f0 libdyld.dylib`misaligned_stack_error_
libdyld.dylib`misaligned_stack_error_:
->  0x97f772f0 <+0>:  movdqa %xmm0, 0x10(%esp)
    0x97f772f6 <+6>:  movdqa %xmm1, 0x20(%esp)
    0x97f772fc <+12>: movdqa %xmm2, 0x30(%esp)
    0x97f77302 <+18>: movdqa %xmm3, 0x40(%esp)
```

trace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x42b83, 0x97f772f0 libdyld.dylib`misaligned_stack_error_, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
  * frame #0: 0x97f772f0 libdyld.dylib`misaligned_stack_error_
    frame #1: 0xa3db5edc libsystem_c.dylib`__sFX + 184
    frame #2: 0x00001ed4 hello`not_called + 84
(lldb) di -n not_called 
hello`not_called:
    0x1e80 <+0>:  pushl  %ebp
    0x1e81 <+1>:  movl   %esp, %ebp
    0x1e83 <+3>:  pushl  %edi
    0x1e84 <+4>:  pushl  %esi
    0x1e85 <+5>:  subl   $0x30, %esp
    0x1e88 <+8>:  calll  0x1e8d                    ; <+13>
    0x1e8d <+13>: popl   %eax
    0x1e8e <+14>: leal   0x105(%eax), %ecx
    0x1e94 <+20>: movl   %ecx, (%esp)
    0x1e97 <+23>: movl   %eax, -0x14(%ebp)
    0x1e9a <+26>: calll  0x1f5c                    ; symbol stub for: printf
    0x1e9f <+31>: xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x1ea1 <+33>: leal   -0x10(%ebp), %edx
    0x1ea4 <+36>: movl   -0x14(%ebp), %esi
    0x1ea7 <+39>: leal   0x118(%esi), %edi
    0x1ead <+45>: movl   %edi, -0x10(%ebp)
    0x1eb0 <+48>: movl   $0x0, -0xc(%ebp)
    0x1eb7 <+55>: movl   -0x10(%ebp), %edi
    0x1eba <+58>: movl   %edi, (%esp)
    0x1ebd <+61>: movl   %edx, 0x4(%esp)
    0x1ec1 <+65>: movl   $0x0, 0x8(%esp)
    0x1ec9 <+73>: movl   %eax, -0x18(%ebp)
    0x1ecc <+76>: movl   %ecx, -0x1c(%ebp)
    0x1ecf <+79>: calll  0x1f56                    ; symbol stub for: execve
    0x1ed4 <+84>: movl   %eax, -0x20(%ebp)
    0x1ed7 <+87>: addl   $0x30, %esp
    0x1eda <+90>: popl   %esi
    0x1edb <+91>: popl   %edi
    0x1edc <+92>: popl   %ebp
    0x1edd <+93>: retl   
    0x1ede <+94>: nop
```

With slight modifications I was able to succeed on a PC running Ubuntu 16.04, I just can't work out this misaligned stack issue.

I'm only starting research on this field so any hints are appreciated!

Edit: (Ubuntu 16.04 attempt)

I was able to succeed without a crash using the very same program compiled with `gcc -fno-stack-protector hello.c -o hello`. It wasn't exactly the same, since it was 64bit this time, but I didn't have 32bit development libraries and succeeded with this setup anyway. ASLR was disabled:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Edit:

I was able to fix the crash by adding `-mrealignstack` and compiling the program with

```
gcc -m32 -mrealignstack -fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wl,-no_pie hello.c -o hello
```

However, I'm still interested in a manual way of fixing it, since this flag seems all too uncommon and introduces overhead of realigning the stack. That being said, there must be a way to realign the stack by hand, I'm just not sure yet *how* to do it.

Edit:

This only crashes when calling library functions, any chain of my own functions executed after hijacking `eip` works.

Comment: To whoever intending to close the question: I'm sorry but I can't see how this is not a programming-related question. If you will direct me to a better suited place then please do so. For the time being, I think SO is the appropriate place. It has `the` minimal code example that should reproduce this behavior on any Mac machine (since the problem is Mac-related).

Comment: Doing a buffer overflow is harder on most modern 64bit machines, they have a canary thats placed on the stack and if the canary changes the program is stopped, for educationsal purposes use an old 32bit linux OS and have some fun http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20497/stack-overflows-defeating-canaries-aslr-dep-nx

Comment: @tesseract I have disabled both the stack canaries (`-fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`) and ASLR (`-Wl,-no_pie`). The Ubuntu I did succeed on was by the way 64bit, and the program was compiled for 64bit as well, and had stack canaries and ASLR disabled too.

Comment: Since `execve` has returned, it has failed. Check `errno`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Unfortunately, the error occurring is a part of that call - it's impossible to get past it. Actually I noticed that other functions returning values crash as well.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Execution reaches 0x1ed4, which means it's not impossible to get there.  Given that `execve` only returns when there's an error, checking `errno` will identify that specific error. What's impossible here?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Impossible since the crash occurs before the next line of code is executed. As I understand it, it happens while retrieving return value, hence the call isn't completely finished.

Comment: I should've been more specific: check the value of `errno` with your debugger.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Obviously, but since it's also a macro dereferencing a pointer returned from a function call (at least on my implementation) I'm also not able to check it. On a side note, I feel the `errno` won't affect anything here, since I can make it crash by just calling for `errno`. Either way, I can't get the error pointer even with internal function (which is `__error()` on my implementation)